# JQuery Mobile Form Submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 2 pages "index.php" and "HomePage.php" :

when i click to sumbit from "index.php" i can't find data post in "Home.php" 
there is the code of "index.php"

- http://jsfiddle.net/wassim/Wu8Lj/1/
- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/Wu8Lj/2/ <-- fixed code

the code of "HomePage.php"  is

```
 <?php

 $place=$_POST["searchBox"]; 
  if (isset($place)){
   $p=$place;   
 }
 else {
    $p='NO DATA';
 }
 ?>

<div data-role="page" id ="acceuil" >
 <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" ><h3>Find<?php echo $p; ?></h3></div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <?php
    echo $p;
    ?>
  </div>
 <div data-role="footer" ><h3>footer</h3></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a `name` to the input field in order to post it which is missing in your markup. Add the name and then you should be good.

```
<input type="search" id="searchBox" name="searchBox" placeholder="(Code postale, Ville, D&eacute;partement ...)">
```

Comment: Can i add to this an animation ? flip for example  $('#dataSearch').bind('submit',function(event){
     
    if (validateFormData()) {
      changePage({
       url:"homePage.php",
       type:"post",
       data:$('#dataSearch').serialize()
   },{transition:'flip'},false);
  }
 });

Comment: I dont have much idea about `changePage` in mobile, you might give it a try.

Comment: hmm, you might have to try something else for transition. but please mark this as an answer thanks.